# Identifying keys with multiple values in a hash table

Tags: python, csv, hashtable

I am a beginner in Python scripting.

I have a CSV file which has 5 columns and over 1000 rows. I am attaching a screenshot to give an idea of how the file looks like. (I have included only 4 rows, but the real file has over 1000 rows). So the task I am trying to achieve is this:

I need to print an output csv file, which prints the rows of original csv file based on following conditions.

- Each "number" field (column1) is supposed to have just one "name" field associated with it. If it has more than one name fields associated with it, it must throw an error (or display a message next to the number in the output.csv)
- If a number field has just one name associated with it, simply print the entire row.

The data in CSV file is in the below format.

`Number            Name                Choices
11234            ABCDEF               A1B6N5
11234            ABCDEF               A2B6C4
11234            EFGHJK               A4F2
11235            ABCDEF               A3F5H7
11236            MNOPQR               F3D4D5`

So my expected output should look something like this. Flag and Message should be displayed only when a "number" has more than one "name" associated with it.
If a "name" has been associated to more than one "number" it should not be flagged. (like 11235 had same name as 11234, but not flagged).

`Number            Name                Choices        Flag        Message
11234                                                 1         More than 1 name
11234

11234

11235            ABCDEF               A3F5H7
11236            MNOPQR               F3D4D5`

I do understand that this can be implemented as a hashtable, where the number serves as a key and the name serves as value. If the value count is more than 1 for any key, we can probably set a flag and print the error message accordingly.

But could someone help me get started with this? As in, how do I implement this in Python?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Unable to add the screenshot of the csv file. I hope the question is clear.

Comment: If it's a text file you can always paste in a few lines in a code block. Or just link to a picture.

Comment: When you say a hashtable, do you mean a python dictionary? If so, i'd suggest reading up on python dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few concepts you should learn and understand first:

Importing and Exporting CSV: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Counter: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

or

Defaultdict(int) for counting: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

It sounds like you need column1 to be the key of a dictionary. If you're trying to count how many times it appears (that's not clear), then you can use `names = defaultdict(int); names[key]+=1`

If all you want is to remove the duplicates with no counting or crash if there's a duplicate, then here's what you can do:

```
mydict = {}
with open('yourfile.csv', mode='r') as infile:
  reader = csv.reader(infile)
  with open('yourfile.csv', mode='w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in reader:
      key = row[0]
      if key in mydict:
        #Could handle this separately
        print "Bad key, already found: %s. Ignoring row: %s" % (key, row)
        raise #Element already found
      mydict[key] = row

    writer.writerows(mydict.values())
```

If this doesn't work, please give us sample input and expected output. Either way, this should get you started. Also, be patient: you'll learn most by doing things wrong and figuring out why they are wrong. Good luck!

====

Update:
You have a few choices. The easiest for a beginning is probably to build two lists and then output them.

Use `key = row[1]`
If key is already in the dictionary, remove it (`del mydict[key]`) and add it to the other dict `multiple_dict = {}; multiple_dict[key] = [number, None, None, Data, Message]`

```
def proc_entry(row):
  key = row[1]
  Saved existing data

  if key in mydict:
    multiple_dict[key] = key, None, None, 1, "Message"
    del mydict[key]
  elif key in multiple_dict:
    #Key was already duplicated, increase flag?
    multiple_dict[key][4]+=1
```

At this point, your code is getting complicated enough to use things like:
`number, name, value = row`, and splitting your code into functions. Then you should test the functions with known input to see if the output is as expected.
i.e. pre-load "mydict", then call your processing function and see how it worked. Even better? Learn to write simple unit tests :) .

While we could write it for you, that's not the spirit of Stackoverflow. If you have any more questions, you might want to split this into precise questions that haven't been answered already. Everything I mentioned above could have been found on Stackoverflow and a bit of practice. Knowing what solution to go for is then the art of programming! Have fun ...or hire a programmer if this isn't fun to you!

Comment: Thank you Pierre for the reply! But here's a question that I have. The CSV file which I am mentioning has data in the following format.

Comment: Your format didn't print here. UFT8? ASCII? or do you mean separators? Either way, sounds like you might just need to learn more python first. Google has a good free python class.